# Tape wrapping on a moving cylinder

Tags: objects

I am wondering if anybody could give me a smart tip how to control the tape on the moving cylinders by constraints or modifier. In the attached animation I keyframed the control points of the tape curve manually (with an empty on each curve bow).
The goal would be to rotate the lower arm and the tape will aligne tangentially to each cylinder.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: in geometry nodes could use filleting and trimming...

Comment: Maybe shapekeys would work

Comment: I tried some smart filleting but didn't work, I guess proper maths have to be employed...